# how to get pixel color from image using x and y coordinates?

Tags: javascript, html, image, jpeg, pixel

What i am tryting to do is
take the "pixel.jpg" and cosole.log the RGB value of 
a pixel at the x and y values determined by a variable. 
im i assuming i would need to 
to create a canvas and then scan
the entire thing using a for loop.. ??

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
title>Pixel</title>
<link href="pixel.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="pixel.js"></script>
```

```
<pre id="output"></pre>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13963308/how-do-you-simply-obtain-an-array-of-pixel-data-from-an-image

Answer (score 0):

Draw the pixel on a canvas. Then use `getImageData`.

```
var getPixelColor = function(img,x,y){
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.width = 1;
    canvas.height = 1;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.drawImage(img,x,y,1,1,0,0,1,1);
    return ctx.getImageData(0,0,1,1);
}
```